Why my docker container is exiting everytime after docker run command
Please help me. I am trying build and RUN a simple docker file using below queries but my container is exiting and not starting manually too.
In Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install nginx -y
COPY . /var/www/html/
CMD {"nginx","-g","daemon off;"}

==> docker build -t image1 .
==> docker run -itd --name cont1 -p 8081:80 image1

99eac98f403d   image1    "/bin/sh -c '{\"nginx…"   9 minutes ago    Exited (127) 9 minutes ago 

Please let me know how to get up a container after a docker run command.

docker logs 99eac98f403d to see what happened.

(Consider using the prebuilt nginx image.  That base image comes with Nginx preinstalled and already has a correct CMD, so you just need to COPY your files into it.)

Your CMD syntax is wrong; it needs to be square brackets for the "exec form":
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

(in which case you'd probably want
CMD ["/usr/bin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

or similar, to qualify the path to nginx.)
or just bare words for the shell form:
CMD nginx -g "daemon off;"

What you have now is being interpreted by the shell, as evident from "/bin/sh -c '{\"nginx…" in the output you show.

Thank you so much its working...................
